# how to upload multiple files using java

Tags: java, file, ftp

I am hoping someone can help me (once again).

I have a very large number of smmll files (over 4000) each only a few K.
I have writen an FTP program in java which will transfer each file individually but it is taking a very long time. Also the handshaking overhead seems to make the problem worse.

What I would like to be able to do is open the FTP connection send all the files then close it again.

I know that this is possible in FTP but quite how to acheive this in java is beyond me.

I currently have the filenames in an array so parsing through them is no problem. I have tried calling the following class and passing it the filename but after several hours it was still moving about 1 file per second.

```
    package website;

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    public class ftpUpload {

public ftpUpload(String target, String savename, String localFilePath) {

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(target + savename + ";type=i");

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedOutputStream out = 
            new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream in = 
            new FileInputStream(localFilePath + savename);

        int i = 0;
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024];
        while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
            out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    }
```

Is there a way I can open the connection with the ftp site username and password,
then send it the files
and finally close the connection?

This would seem to me easier than creating multiple threads to send files concurrently.

Any advice greatfully received.

Paul

Comment: Would it be acceptable to ZIP them up, then upload only the compressed file? That can be really easily done in Java.

Comment: Can you zip up the files and send the zip file instead? Or is the server expecting individual files?

Comment: Why do you not create an archive of all the files, and send one file instead of several K's?

Comment: There are two ways for you to go. First off, about FTP: One file per Data connection. Period. You can't transfer multiple files with the same data connection. So either you send them one at a time ('PASV', 'STOR')...or you pack them into a Zip file and send that.

Comment: @DNA: does it make this a ZIPLICATE post? Then we're in deep trouble :)

Comment: Can you start several threads and give each of them a "slice" of your array of file names to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to send multiple files in one session using URLConnection, this means you get the overhead of opening and closing the session for every file.

FTPClient from [commons net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) does support multiple operations in one session. For example (exception handling ommitted):

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect("ftp.example.com");
ftp.login("admin", "secret");
ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

for(File file : files) {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    ftp.storeFile(file.getName(), in);
    in.close();
}

ftp.disconnect();
```

This should help.

If you still need better performance, I don't see any other alternative than using multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am now using FTPClient as suggested AND multi-threading.

Comment: Good to hear! Just out of curiosity: How big performance improvement did you get? And please click accept if you're happy with the answer.

Comment: You can if the server accepts it get a massive performance increase. I tried 40 concurrent connections and the files simply few to the server - up until it invariably errors out. This is probably down to concurrent connection limitations with public servers, that said if you are incontrol of the network and the ftp server this is definately the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't mean you get the open/close overhead every file. `HttpURLConnection` does connection-pooling behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of testing I have found reliability issues with multiple ftp threads to public servers which is what I need in this case. Most (if not all) ftp servers limit the maximum number of connections and also limit the maximum number of concurrent connections from the same IP address. Two concurrent connections from the same IP seems to be the only guaranteed maximum you are allowed. The realistic option as suggested above is to zip the files and ftp a single file. You can unzip the file when it gets there using an php script (as long as the server supports unzip you will need to check if this included in the php build). Finally if like me you need to upload in excess of 10,000 files many ftp servers will not show more than 9998 files (10,000 inlcuding . and ..)
If anyone knows of an ftp server free or cheap that supports ZipArchive in the php build and will list more than 9998 files when requesting a file listing in ftp can you please let me know.....